# Wordpress theme breaks existing jquery plugins

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I made a custom wordpress theme for a company, and I am using the wp_cycle plugin on the homepage. The wp_cycle plugin only functions when my theme is not installed.

I can't find a js library conflicts and the web inspector does not show any errors. Can anyone help me diagnose the problem?

http://www.circularknitservices.com

Comment: probably going to need to see it with the custom theme

Comment: Please activate your custom theme

Comment: is the plugin activatated? because it should load the file `wp-content/plugins/wp-cycle/jquery.cycle.all.min.js` but it's not.

Comment: The plugin is activated. The file you mentioned is also in its respective place. I don't understand why it wouldn't be pulling in the file.

Comment: I don't understand either, really. Besides, plugin *is* adding some css, so it's semi-operational. Give this a try: edit wp-cycle.php, replace `add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'wp_cycle_scripts');` with `add_action('init', 'wp_cycle_scripts');` since codex says not to use 'wp_print_scripts' hook to call wp_enqueue_script() as to plugin is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You do have an error; use the error console to see "Result of expression '$' [undefined] is not a function."

Remove the other js libraries to narrow down the issue.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ to be sure you are running jQuery in no conflict mode even when not using other libraries.

Comment: No other js library is attached. The problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

change all your uses of $() to jQuery().  that way any namespace conflicts with other frameworks are irrelevant.  should get you working.

Comment: Plugins using jquery don't work if I have the starkers theme in the theme folder. I don't see where I ould have a jquery conflict. Te plugin is also broken with the stock twenty 10 theme. The plugin only works when I don't have my the theme in the themes folder.

Comment: @Alex, i understand you may think it is unlikely, but have you tried my suggestion?  if not, try it.  it will work.

Comment: I understand that your suggestion will work, but I did not write any jquery for my theme. I don't see where the conflict would be. Could you point it out? The wp_cycle plugin is supposed to pull the Jquery in automatically.